# Does a point exist in the real world

Tags: soft-question, spacetime, discrete

In mathematics we can have an infinite number of points between two integers.

This is really circular logic since a point is defined as infinitely small.

Does a point exist anywhere in the physical world or is it simply a convenient mathematical abstraction with no place in reality.

**Is space actually divided into infinitely small points? What about time?**

Comment: A point doesn't really "exist" in mathematics either.  It's the result of a limit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35674/is-time-continuous and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4453/how-could-spacetime-become-discretised-at-the-planck-scale

Comment: Also closely related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64197/is-there-anything-physically-infinite .