# Minimum amount of space

Tags: spacetime, discrete

I always believed that there were no limits in the world and then I learned that a minimum temperature exists, and maybe a maximum speed. And now I am wondering about the boundaries of the world.

Is there a minimum amount of space? Is the world like a chessboard and something can't move less than a specific distance or occupy less than a specific amount of space? I suppose this can't be proved practically, but is there an answer to this theoretically?

Comment: No, in physics there's not a minimum amount of space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/)

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32806/, among others.