# Questions regarding space

Tags: vacuum, space

A difficulty I face is when I think of space. I haven't studied GR or SR yet, but I really want to know what it is. What is space? Is it just the empty place where things are in reality, or something else?

Another question: While reading about forces at a distance, like gravitational force, magnetic force, electric force etc, I got a really good statement which explained why non-contact forces exist. The statement was: Non-contact forces exist because some particles tend to change the space around them, for instance, a charged particle changes the space around it, and it can be felt by another charge particle, which leads to their attraction or repulsion. Now, my question is this: If I am right saying that space is just the empty place where things are present in reality, shouldn't the change in space be experienced by every object? For example: Suppose an electric charge changes the space around it(I don't know what happens, just a guess), and it leads to another opposite charge being attracted to it. Now, shouldn't every object be attracted or repulsed, as space is the same for every object, charged or not, isn't it? So why these forces are limited to specific particles only?

NOTE: I am not a physics specialist, I am just a student, and like to study it. If these questions are stupid, please forgive me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. We prefer one question per post otherwise the answers get a bit involved. You've asked (at least!) three separate questions, and in fact some of your questions have been asked already on this site.

Comment: Also related: [Is space-time a special form of energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111573/)

Comment: Your last paragraph is really complicated because we describe the electromagnetic, strong and weak forces using quantum field theory and the gravitational force using spacetime curvature.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you have asked what space is. Space is defined as the boundless three-dimensional extent in which objects and events have relative position and direction. (I don’t think the boundlessness part has been proved yet.)It is a vacuum.

For your second question, you have asked, if I interpret correctly, if every object is attracted to every other object in the universe. The answer is YES, they are, but the mass and/or distances of/between the bodies is so great that the effect of the attraction is so small that it is absolutely negligible.The friction acting on the bodies can also contribute to the decrease of the effect of the attraction.

Comment: Hello Atri De and welcome to Physics SE. Please refrain from providing answers that you are not sure about. I am not saying that your answer is incorrect (not my physics field anyway), but "comments" like "correct me if I am saying anything wrong" show that you may not be 100% sure about your answer. I encourage you to either do some studying before answering and if you are not sure provide the information you found and the source containing it, or answer only questions you are sure you know the answer. I hope I didn't discourage you and hope to see more of your answers in Physics SE.

Comment: So sorry deleting the PS right away, actually this is my first answer in this website so i was a bit nervous, even though I am pretty sure my answer is correct.