# Are energy and momentum imposed by purely geometrical properties of spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, matter

If we defined spacetime as a purely geometrical (not physical) structure of the kind that is in general relativity (a 4-dimensional Lorentzian manifold), would it automatically have properties that would behave like energy and momentum in Einstein field equations?

I am wondering whether the purely geometrical properties of a 4D Lorentzian manifold impose existence of matter (that is, properties that behave like energy and momentum).

From what I have read, it seems that the answer is no, and so energy and momentum seem to be encoded in the points of the manifold rather than in its geometry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is space-time a special form of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111573/2451)

Answer (score 0):

Given a Lorentzian manifold, one can calculate $$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}$$
If you want, you can declare that this quantity represents energy and momentum, and then the Einstein field equations are satisfied. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, I am asking whether this manifold necessarily has the properties of energy and momentum. It seems that energy and momentum are just added to the manifold by choice.

Comment: Which properties? This has the property "satisfies Einstein's field equations." What other equations do you want satisfied?

Comment: Does this manifold _necessarily_ satisfy Einstein's field equations? Do Einstein's field equations logically follow from the geometrical properties of this manifold?

Comment: All the manifold gives you is topological structure and $g$. The point is that for any $g$, there necessarily exists a $T$ that satisfies the field equations - the manifold doesn't come with this $T$ built-in, but you are free to define it. 
When people say "geometrical properties", they usually mean equations only involving $g$. So no, in that sense Einstein's equations don't follow from geometrical properties.

Comment: I was told that the manifold has energy and momentum also when T=0 because there are gravitational waves defined purely by geometrical properties of the manifold. So it seems that for this special case, the manifold indeed has energy and momentum necessarily?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "has energy and momentum necessarily" - can you formalize that? Or give examples of what kind of property you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, apparently I misunderstood about the necessity of energy and momentum when T=0, so the manifold does not necessarily have energy or momentum when T=0.