# Is the position of matter discrete in universe?

Tags: spacetime, discrete

In computer, for example, if we use integer to represent position of objects, position can be (0,0) , (3,5), but not in (1.5,3.5).

In real world, there are something that is discrete, such as atomic energy level. Is there similar concept about the matter(eg: quark) that can exists in some position only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/)