# Is the space of possible positions of a particle in QM discrete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, discrete

I recently updated my understanding about quantum mechanics from popular science level to basic undergraduate level.

What surprised me is that for the quantum state of a particle, the wave function for that state using the position of that particle as a basis, is a function defined on the continuum.

I understand now how there can be a discrete space of energy levels of a particle when it is trapped.

- But when it comes to the position of a particle, **does the fact that we represent the state of a particle as a continuous wave function on position space mean that QM states that the position of a particle can potentially be observed anywhere on the continuum?**
- similarly, Im not sure how this works for non trapped particles. It seems energy is not quantized there since momentum alao has a wave function defined on the continuum, so **does that mean that the space of possible kinetic energy levels for a non trapped particle is not discrete?**
- if the answers to these questions are yes, how does this square with my popular science understanding that there is a minimum segment in space, time, and energy levels given by plancks constant?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39208/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

to answer your questions:

1> Yes, that is the case.

2> Yes, that is the case also. However, I don't really understand what you mean by "the momentum also has a wavefunction". Do you refer to the Fourier transform of the spatial wavefunction.

3> The segment you refer to is not in constrast to the previous statements. Planck's constant $\hbar$ always comes into play. For example, if you remember the hamiltonian eigenvalues at the harmonic oscillator:
$$E_n=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega$$

Comment: +1  Good answer.  But I think you could improve your answer to number 3.  It's not just that $\hbar$ comes into play.  The question seemed to be suggesting that "popular" accounts of QM indicate that everything — including space and time — are discrete, and the size of those discrete dimensions are given by the Planck length and Planck time.  This site has plenty of good answers to that question, like [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9721/8007) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/33289/8007) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/35676/8007).

Comment: 2> yes I mean the fourier transform of the spatial wavefunction. 3> But the harmonic oscillator is only one system. My question is: if it is possible for a partical to have a momentum anywhere on the continuum, and energy is a function of momentum, then it is not the case that there is only a discrete set of possible energy levels, so the idea that there is a minimum possible change in position or energy level (which is an idea I got from popular science articles) would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your third question, the Plank length might be what you consider the "quantized" space and the Plank time is the "quantized" time. These are fundamental ideas for loop-quantum gravity, but not a result of the Schrodinger equation or quantum mechanics.

In quantum mechanics, the frequency (and thus energy) of a particle's wavefunction are quantized, but it may be found anywhere in space. The probability of finding it in a region is given by the integral of the amplitude squared of the particle's wavefunction over that region.