# Discrete structure of moving light in space-time. Does the light actually moving or it is triggered by cells of space-time?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, photons, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

I have an idea that seems for me interesting and exotic.
It is not about a traveling with speed of light or observing a frozen light.   Rather it is about the nature of light/photons and discrete structure of space-time. No material object can move exactly with speed of lights (there is no much energy for it), it is impossible to observe an frozen light. But the space-time cells can be activated in a way that seems that light are moving with the known speed of it.

My question about cells of space-time and they are not material until activated.
Can a photon not move in space in classical terms of understanding?
Can it happen so that instead of moving along a straight line, the movement is obtained this way: after certain intervals of time certain points (the points of space-time not classics material points) in space-time structure  are activated/deactivated. What I mean is that the light isn't moving in a way that the other macro objects are moving. I mean that light movement is some kind of wave of space-time points. Photon doesn't move continuously in space-time, rather it's a wave of space-time points and also according to this idea it becomes clear why the photon does not have a rest mass.

As an explanatory example I can give this analogy. Imagine that there is a display and a few pixels on it. At first the first pixel is turns on then it is turns off then the second one is turns on and after some time period it turns off and so consistently all the pixels. And for the outside observer is seems that the light is moving on (on the display). My idea is that on the space-time the light moves like in example above.

Comment: Why it is duplicate ? I am talking about different thing.

Comment: In what specific way is it different?

Comment: I agree that no material object can move exactly with speed of lights (there is no much energy for it), it is impossible to observe an frozen light.  But the space-time cells can be activated in a way that seems that light are moving with the known speed of it.My question about cells of space-time and they are not material until activated. I mean that.

Comment: Please, when you put the minuses do not forget also write explanatory comments.

Comment: What does "not material until activated" mean?

Comment: This is not a complete theory, it is just an idea and I can't give an exact answer.
If you want, suppose that these points are from physical vacuum or from other dimensions or they are cells of the cloth of space-time or some "virtual" points/cells ...

Comment: So the parts that differ from the identical answer are, at present, meaningless. Hence the duplicate designation.

Comment: Duplicate means that there are same/identical questions. The other question(my question has been marked duplicate of it) is about different thing.

Comment: It's not about a different thing if the only thing that's different about your question is in terms of things you can't define.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80557/discussion-between---and-probably-someone).

Comment: It is not a duplicate anymore since OP change the question. However now the question (v11) seems unclear/off-topic.

Comment: Well, I can describe it by analogy. Imagine that there is a display and a few pixels on it. At first the first pixel is turns on then it is turns off then the second one is turns on and after some time period it turns off and so consistently all the pixels. And for the outside observer is seems that the light is moving on (on the display). My idea is that on the space-time the light moves like in example above.

Comment: v12 seems to be a duplicate of [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/84967), [Is time continuous or discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/84967) and links therein.

Comment: Concerning certain flags that have been raised on this question: moderators only over-ride voted decisions in cases that have clearly gone completely off the rails. The mechanism for getting a closed question re-opened is voting by users with at least 3000 rep, *not* a direct appeal to the moderators.