# Can a region of space-time be viewed as a particle with properties of it's own?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime, time

Can a piece of space-time having 3 spacial dimensions and 1 dimension of time be viewed as a particle?  Could this piece of space-time have properties of its own (mass, spin, charge) independent of the energy that it coexists with?  How small would it be, and how much mass does a "volume time" of space time have?  Like, say a 
$light second^3s$?.  Also, since time can be measured forwards or backwards could you have a -$light second^3s$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/is-spacetime-discrete-or-continuous), [Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/84967).

Comment: Regardless of whether space-time has a smallest piece, I am interested in whether a region of space-time can be viewed as a particle with properties. @AccidentalFourierTransform