# What does "continuous spacetime" mean?

Tags: spacetime, terminology, soft-question, quantum-gravity

I often encounter discussions, such as seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/is-spacetime-discrete-or-continuous?), about whether spacetime is discrete or continuous. However, I am only familiar with continuity as being a property of functions. I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822769/how-to-axiomize-the-notion-of-continuous-space) about continuous spaces, but I didn't find a definitive answer there, so I ask what is meant when we say that spacetime is "continuous?" Does it mean that its locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{3+1}$ or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Spacetime is defined as a [Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)

> A manifold is a topological space that locally resembles Euclidean space near each point. More precisely, an $n$-dimensional manifold, or $n$-manifold for short, is a topological space with the property that each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space of dimension $n$.

More precisely, spacetime is a Lorentzian manifold, for which replace Euclidean space with Minkowski spacetime.