# Discreteness of the universe and evidence for simulation

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, discrete

To my untrained thinking, the Planck length / Planck time implies there is a fundamental granularity or quantisation to the universe. In other words, the universe has a certain “resolution” such that matter cannot occupy the space between Planck lengths. I suppose this would imply an absolute grid of some kind.

As a computer programmer, my interest in this comes from thinking that it might support the idea that we’re in a simulation. The other thing that may support this is the many-worlds interpretation of the wave function collapse. If something was wanting to simulate all possibilities in our universe, branching the simulation at the most fundamental level (the wave function) would make sense. Discreteness also makes sense in order to have the simulation require a finite (but mind boggling) amount of memory, assuming there is no purely analytical description of it.

Final thought: holographic projection could be a compression technique they are using ;)

Short version of the question: is the universe fundamentally discrete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/t)