# If spacetime is discrete, would we observe continuous models to show non-rounding and non-truncation errors?

Tags: spacetime, computational-physics, universe, discrete

Typically, the ground truth is taken to be the continuous model. Numerical simulations are taken to be the approximation. These simulations deviate from the continuous model due to both a constant rounding error and truncation error that accumulates with time. You can see an example here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235194/

In the answer there you can see how these types of errors combine to lead to a "sweet spot" of highest accuracy. Ie, the approximation becomes less accurate at very small or large scales. This reminded me of General Relativity, which yields very good predictions at solar system scales but has issues at galaxy (~10^12 larger) and atomic (~10^24 smaller) scales.

I'm wondering if anyone has explored the *reverse* happening. Ie, we take a discrete model to be the ground truth.

I'd guess that with current technology the continuous model would still be a better approximation than discrete, since people aren't running simulations with 10^30 steps per second. But perhaps deviations from the continuous model observed in nature can be taken to support discrete over continuous spacetime.

Comment: I would point out that we already know from modelling solids that periodic lattices of discrete elements interacting, how some of the properties would change from a continuum version of the same. We simply haven't been able to observe any such deviation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33273/)

Comment: @hft Nope, I am wondering specifically about inverting the concepts of rounding and truncation error. In particular, if that would imply modelling a discrete spacetime as continuous would lead to deviations at very large and small scales. GR, for example, was developed to explain observations of the solar system. It was before we knew even about galaxies. My question is whether the errors due to assuming a continuum (if reality is discrete) could be negligible at solar system scale but accumulate to cause deviations from observation at the galaxy-level. Likewise at very small scales.

Comment: Rounding and truncation error of what?

Comment: The usual case is dealing with rounding and truncation error due to using a numerical approximation of a continuous model (the latter is assumed to be the gold standard). But if in reality spacetime is discrete, then I'd expect we see the same types of errors when comparing prediction to observation due to *not* rounding and truncating the calculations.

Comment: It seems like you do not understand that the _difference_ between discrete and continuous is the essence of your question, and that is why it is a duplicate. If you understood the point of doing such approximations, you would also know that it is categorically impossible for these approximations to fail to capture the large scale behaviour properly, by definition, because if they fail, then they are not even a tolerable continuum approximation. As such, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate even if you disagree; what you do need, is more thought and clarity into this problem.

Comment: *it is categorically impossible for these approximations to fail to capture the large scale behaviour properly*. It is not only possible, it is the main difficulty that numerical modellers face. Look up leapfrog integration or see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

Comment: A numerical computation vs a continuous function, I wonder if that is the same as discrete vs continuous physical behavior. After all, water or air is fundamentally a discrete substance of molecules. But the continuous fluid model makes basically perfect predictions for macroscopic behavior, except in fringe cases like near-vacuum.  For spacetime (if Planck scale quantization is true) there are far more than 10^23 discrete units per macroscopic unit. So the behavior may only manifest in fringe cases we can't observe yet.

Comment: You may be interested in the observations described in this recent paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.13726

Comment: @RC_23 Yes, it seems you understand what I am asking about.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin That paper seems highly speculative to me. Eg, those lines are not derived from any theory afaict.

Comment: @Livid. Indeed, I intended that reference as a (very recent) experimental counterpart of the topic in your question. The paper just provides some statistical computations that would justify looking for further measurements - I would not call that speculation, as it is indeed rather agnostic on the theoretical side. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

> Typically, the ground truth is taken to be the continuous model.

I would dispute that point. In e.g. the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) (and many other lattice models), the fundamental degrees of freedom of the theory are discrete, and it is the continuum formulation which is the approximation - typically arrived at via some coarse graining procedure.  In solid state physics, all physical samples have a finite volume and therefore the electronic states have a discrete energy spectrum, but in the interest of simplicity one takes the thermodynamic limit in which the volume goes to infinity and e.g. the density of states becomes continuous.

The kinds of "errors" that can arise from this procedure depend on how coarse the approximation actually is. One interesting example is when one considers magnetic skyrmions, which are topological solitions in the magnetization field of a magnetic material.  The magnetization $\mathbf m(\mathbf x)$ is treated as a continuous function, from which one can calculate the energy of a magnetic configuration.  Since there is a term in the energy functional which depends on the spatial gradient of $\mathbf m$, a discontinuity would require infinite energy - which suggests that topological solitons like magnetic skyrmions should be completely stable.

Of course, this analysis discounts the fact that the magnetization is *not* continuous when you zoom in close enough, and indeed one of the annihilation modes for magnetic skyrmions is that they may shrink to the point where the continuum approximation fails and then simply pop out of existence with the flipping of a handful of spins.

---

On a more philosophically interesting note, if you study the Ising model on a finite domain, then you will find that there is no such thing as ferromagnetism or permanent magnetization. It is only in the limit as the number of sites goes to infinity - in which the average magnetization becomes a continuously-varying quantity rather than a discrete one - that a magnetic phase transition can occur. This suggests that the existence of permanent magnetism is itself an "error" which we obtain by taking a limit in which a certain quantity becomes continuous.

Interestingly enough, we *want* to make this kind of error. In reality, there are no such thing as permanent magnets - but if the chunk of iron in my hand will retain its stable magnetization for a hundred trillion lifetimes of the universe, then I would far prefer to make the "error" that the magnetism is permanent rather than to make the technically correct statement that in the limit of infinite time, all magnetization is transient.

Comment: This seems related but doesn't quite answer my question. If the phenomenon under study is discrete, and you can scale your discrete model to match, then it will perform better than continuous. We cannot currently do this for spacetime because if it really is discrete, it is at a level many orders of magnitude smaller than we are capable of simulating. One question that may help though, what happens when you apply the continuous Ising model to something much larger? Like a neutron star?

Comment: @Livid To be clear, what I mean to say is that we very often start with discrete models (or more generally, models in which certain features take discrete values) and then, in the interest of simplification, approximate those features as continuous ones. In other words, sometimes it is discrete -> continuous which is the approximation, and the errors in this approximation typically take the form of infinities (which arise when when considering gradients in our only-approximately continuous function) or non-analytic behavior which is provably absent with a finite number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you talk about applying the Ising model to a neutron star.

Comment: I used a neutron star as an object much larger than originally considered with a strong magnetic field. If that is inappropriate imagine an iron bar the size of a planet, or whatever makes sense. Wikipedia gives an equation after saying: *The energy of a configuration σ is given by the Hamiltonian function*. Does the continuous approximation become less accurate at predicting the energy this scale?

Comment: @Livid If you have a continuous function which, for computational purposes, you approximate as being discrete, then the discretization errors occur because you are sampling a continuous function at a finite set of points and can accumulate over large scales if e.g. you are integrating. I get the sense that you are searching for an analogous phenomenon with the discrete -> continuous approximation, but in many cases it's not really like that. When you coarse grain a discrete theory to obtain a continuous one, you're fundamentally changing the theory itself, not merely performing a calculation.

Comment: Given a continuous magnetization function $\mathbf m$, you can write down an energy function $F[m] = \int \mathrm d^3x \ \alpha |\mathbf m(\mathbf x)|^2 + \beta |\nabla \mathbf m(\mathbf x)|^2 + \ldots$ which defines its energy, as per Landau's theory. Given a discrete Ising model, you can compute the energy of a configuration by evaluating the Hamiltonian in the wiki article you refer to. It's not at all straightforward to see how you might describe one as being more or less accurate than the other *a priori*.

Comment: In the interest of not completely ignoring your question, I think the answer you're looking for is no - generally speaking, the errors introduced by approximating a discrete quantity as a continuous one do not scale with system size (often, it's the reverse). The errors tend to emerge on the scale of the underlying lattice, and so become problematic when the system is small.

Comment: Thanks, the error at small scales makes sense. What if *time* is one of the discrete variables being (assumed incorrectly) modeled as continuous? Ie, we are looking at dynamics, not snapshots.