# What's the resolution of gravitational time dilation?

Tags: time-dilation

Time dilation near a gravitating mass depends on the distance to that mass. So I assume that time at 1 meter from a very massive object goes slightly slower than at 1.01 meters, and also slower than at 1.000001 meters. Is there a (theoretical) `minimum distance limit` at which time dilation remains the same?

I mean, is there any distance `d`, at any point in space `p` (near a very massive object) at which anything situated at `+-d` from the point would experience the same time dilation experienced at `p`?

Comment: Gravitational force varies smoothly with distance. Gravitational potential varies smoothly with distance. Why would gravitational time dilation not do the same?

Comment: @Ghoster I think that gravitational time dilation varies smoothly, but not infinitely smoothly. I mean, I assume that the distance "d" from my question cannot be smaller than the Plank length, but I was thinking if it might be at least a little bit greater. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: There is no evidence that the Planck length is the smallest length. And in General Relativity, the theory that predicts gravitational time dilation, there is no theoretical smallest length.

Comment: Related: [Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/is-spacetime-discrete-or-continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, there's no evidence of a minimum distance limit. Last year, JILA researchers published the results of a observations of [gravitational time dilation from a 1mm altitude difference](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2022/02/jila-atomic-clocks-measure-einsteins-general-relativity-millimeter-scale) in Earth gravity.

Bothwell et al. Nature volume 602, pages 420–424 (2022)

Answer (score 0):

For special relativity:

$$ \gamma = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1 - 2E/mc^2}}$$

where $E = \frac 1 2 mv^2$ is the newtonian kinetic energy term.

Gravitational time dilation is similar:

$$ t_f/t_0 = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-2GM/rc^2}} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-2U/mc^2}}$$

where $U = GMm/r$ is the Newtonian potential energy term.

So now you can wing it: A neutron star has around $a=10^{12}g$ gravity, so with

$$ v = \sqrt{2ah} $$

you can go from there.