# What were Feynman's objection(s) to a cubic lattice universe?

Tags: spacetime, discrete

In [this video of Feynman discussing the scientific method](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYPapE-3FRw), starting at around eight minutes and 30 seconds, Feynman describes the proposition that space consists of a cubic lattice of points (as opposed to space being continuous).  Feynman says "then we can prove that [the proposition] immediately is wrong," but he doesn't elaborate on the proof.

> My question is: What are the objection(s) to a cubic lattice universe that Feynman refers to in this video?

I'm not looking for every possible objection to a cubic lattice universe.  I'm wondering what in particular the (apparently immediate and obvious) objections are that made Feynman so dismissive of the idea.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 and links therein.