# Is not the idea of a continuous universe and finite information density mutually exclusive?

Tags: universe, information

As far as I understand, the universe is not divided into discrete units, but rather its 
continuous.

This seems backed up by a quick search:

[Does the Planck scale imply that spacetime is discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/does-the-planck-scale-imply-that-spacetime-is-discrete)

I have also heard, however, that there is a finite amount of information in the universe. There is a finite "density" to which information can be stored.

If this is correct I am having trouble reconciling these two things in my head.

Surely in any continuous line, even in a single dimension, a single point can express any number to any precision? Is this not infinite information...at least some type of infinite.

Now I am not saying we can ever store or extract information of course - merely if a objects position doesn't have discrete units then its position akin to a point on that line. So even one object needs infinite information to express its location, thus infinite information is "stored" in its position - and in fact in the positions of every particle in the universe.

I've been racking my head as to what I am missing but I cant see it. :?

Any help?

Thanks,

**Notes;** 
I am aware that on small scales there is a certain "noise" to things. That..I think...we can only get "probability maps" not precise locations of any subatomic particle. 
But is not the centre of such probability maps also a non-discrete position? Even if its changing constantly?

Comment: A universe can be continuous and infinite and yet empty. There's (alomst) no information then, and certainly a finite amount, and these things are not contradictory.

Comment: Note that uncertainty principle is some systems quantize the energy spectra. Energy is not discrete however. The spacetime could be doing the same thing, actually this is a consequence of norm in hilbert space + locality.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Good point with a hypothetical there. In fact, would not in that scenario an infinite empty universe in fact have less information then a finite empty one? (which at least has its size itself as a value)