# If you have two Planck lengths extended from one point forming a right angle, whats the length of the hypotenuse?

Tags: spacetime, physical-constants, discrete, absolute-units

Can we do measurements at this scale seeing that the length of the hypotenuse would have a value at a length that cant exist (1.4 Planck lengths)? Or is my interpretation of the [Planck length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) incorrect?

Comment: You can think about a hypothetical quantity whatever you like because fiction is never wrong. The Planck length, at this point, is purely fictional.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 and links therein.