# Is the universe a lattice?

Tags: spacetime, time, universe, discrete

My understanding is that cause and effect create a partial order of events in the universe (and that relatively prevents anything stronger).

My understanding is also that it’s generally useless to talk about “things” in the context of physics. The laws of physics describe events, not objects.

The Big Bang can be seen as the “greatest lower bound” of all events (it must happen before anything else can happen). Similarly the “heath death of the universe” could be seen as the “least upper bound” of all events. No event can happen after it, and all other events must happen before it.

So, the answer would seem to be yes (everything describable by physics forms a lattice).

Has anyone formulated such a notion: the universe is simply the lattice of all events?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually a duplicate, because though the answer would be similar to [those here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/does-the-planck-scale-imply-that-spacetime-is-discrete), I think that the 2 questions would be indexed very differently by Google and other search engines because of the terminology used. One major focus of SE is that there is a certain amount of traffic which should be generated by search results, and this may improve that. Just my opinion though... I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Comment: @Qmechanic Why would “the universe as a lattice of events” require time to be discrete? Wouldn’t you just end up with a lattice with uncountable height if time was continuous?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, since it is about a mathematical lattice order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate. OP's usage of the word "lattice" is somewhat unconventional in physics (cf. [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) vs. [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group))). Voting to reopen.

Comment: @ScottWisniewski Note that space-like separated events cannot be given a total ordering. Only causally-connected (i.e., timelike) events can be ordered that way.

Comment: A lattice made from the partial order of causal events is the basis of the causal set quantum gravity