# Does having a minimum length in space violate Lorentz invariance?

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity, lorentz-symmetry, discrete

I’m trying to understand different approaches to quantum gravity. One involves quantising space and time themselves, which i believe can result in there being a minimum possible length and time interval. My question is, does making space discrete like this violate lorentz invariance? From special relativity we know that length contraction is a thing, so would having a minimum length cause a problem?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 and links therein.