# Does quantum chromodynamics imply continuous space?

Tags: spacetime, electrons, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, discrete

I am thinking it does.

That's because a pillar of quantum chromodynamics is renormalization, which is itself due to the assumption that electrons are point particles (having no extent).  A point particle has no place in a discrete universe, as it wouldn't exist at all.

This question is asking the specific question about renormalization and the assumptions of electron radius, and just the broad issue of quantum mechanics itself.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9076/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The question relies on the misconception that renormalization occurs due to assuming "point particles". QFT has no concept of "point particle" in the classical sense, and renormalization does not arise due to this - there are several ways to state it, but the Wilsonian standpoint is that renormalization is simply lowering or raising the momentum cutoff of the QFT, which would correspond to making the discretized spacetime lattice the theory can be defined on finer or coarser. The final QFT formalism usually deals with the (supposedly existent) continuum limit of this lattice.